# When compiling I get warnings without line or column

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting warnings in a code I have to fix but those warning only say which file they are on, not the line (=0).

All those warnings are *Implicit conversion from 'Object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.'*

It wouldn't be a problem if those warning didn't fill the list so I get a *Maximum number of warnings has been exceeded* so I don't know if there are more warnings (that I can fix).

Is there any way to know were those warnings come from?

Comment: What happens if you double-click the warnings? Are they on a form? (with a designer)

Comment: @TimSchmelter there are no pdb files

Comment: @SLaks, if I double-click nothing happens. And they are on a form, yes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You're thinking of stack traces.

Comment: This is an issue from the form designer.  Did you edit any .Designer files?

Comment: @SLaks it's not my code so maybe. I know I didn't edit it. Any way to correct this issue?

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then the IDE should point out where things are not correctly typed before you even try compiling. If you get an overwhelming number of errors, then I suggest using `Option Strict On` at the top of one file at a time instead of enabling it for the whole project.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewMorton. I can (try) fix(ing) those warnings now. At least I know what they are ;-)